# swift uitextview limit number of line breaks to two at the time

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I wonder if its possible to limit the number of line break that you can do in row?

I have set a limit to the number of characters that can be inserted but users can still insert text like:

```
Sometext
(line break) 
(line break) 
(line break) 
(line break) 
(line break) 
(line break) 
some more text...
```

Is it possible to only low two line breaks at the time? So that the above text ends up like:

```
Some text
(line break)
(line break)
some more text...
```

Since I cant edit the text backend I must do it in the fronend.

I want too clean out the text and limit the amount of line breaks in a row to two after the user has finished typing

Comment: Your question isn't clear. When do you wish to "clean up" the text? As the user is typing it or some other time? Show any relevant code you already have for this.

Comment: @rmaddy I want to clean the text after the has typed. Updated my question.

Comment: Then what part of this do you need help with? Is it the string processing or getting the text after the user is done entering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are 3 newline characters in a row in the text in the UITextView, you can replace them with only 2 newline characters.

```
while str.contains("\n\n\n") {
    str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n\n", with: "\n\n")
}
```